# Google drive API files list size <= 100 when specify fields parameter

Tags: google-drive-api

When i specify **fields** parameter in files list request, i only get **100 records** of files in response. But in API documentation written about pageSize parameter: "*The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are **1 to 1000**, inclusive. (Default: 100)*".

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=500&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2C%20name%2C%20parents%2C%20mimeType%2C%20owners%2C%20permissions)' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

only 100 records max in response

Comment: What happens if you remove fields?

Comment: when i remove permissions field in files and specify pageSize=1000 i have 460 records in response. when i remove parents in files i have 1000 records in response

Comment: Submit a bug report here https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025 theres something wrong there.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve files from a Shared Drive as well by chance?

Comment: No, from personal google drive account. I test some different accounts with more than 1000 files. I used api explorer: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true to test api.

Answer (score 2):

### As a workaround I'd avoid using "fields" parameter if a wanted to retrieve 1000 items

There's already a public report regarding this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154155376

This is normal due to the limit of characters. The limit is dependent on both the server and the client used so when it comes to add more characters, Drive API will try to reduce the characters length sent in the payload.

In a summary, you should reduce the size of files to retrieve if those fields are mandatory.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) says `pageSize -> The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)`

If you find this to be a blocker for your application, Google recommends to use [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features) in order to report a bug or ask for a new feature.

### As a different approach specify the pageToken in your requests

By following your request template, here are the changes:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=100&pageToken=[TOKEN]&fields=nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, mimeType, owners, permissions)' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

As I mentioned before due to the HTTP limitations on server side use the page **nextPageToken** that you get in the response and request 100 items so you can avoid these limitations.

Keep in mind that this approach will need more requests than before.